# Passing Observable to another component in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have two components `details` and `details-view`.

In the `details` I have to pass obserwable by `@Input()` into second component.

Details Component

```
 res$: (id: number, type: string) => Observable<DetailsResponse[]>;
 constructor(private service: Service) {
  this.res$ = service.getData;
 }
```

Service

```
 getData(id: number, type: string): Observable<DetailsResponse[]>{
   const params = new HttpParams().append('typename', type);
   return this.http.get<any>('api/id', {params: params});
 }
```

Detalis-View HTML

`<dwtalis-view [resources$]="res$"></dwtalis-view>`

Detalis-Viev TS Component

```
@Input()
resouces$: Observable<DetailsResponse[]>
```

My question is how to subscribe and get the data from `resources$` observable in the detalis view component. Subscribing this object retunrs error "resources$ is not a finction can not subscribe"

Comment: Assuming this isn't a typo: `this.res$ = service.getData` is just passing the function definition. If you actually want an observable, you need to execute the function `this.res$ = service.getData()`. Alternatively, if you do mean to pass the function definition then your typing for `resource$` is wrong, and it should be `(id: number, type: string) => Observable<DetailsResponse[]>` to match `res$` from the parent component

Comment: like vlad said you are passing function instead of observable. In your case you need to call that resources$() function to get the observable out from it. resources$().subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typing doesn't match. `res$` is a function `(id: number, type: string) => Observable<DetailsResponse[]>`, but `resouces$` is an observable `Observable<DetailsResponse[]>`;

Based on your comments, you need to pass a function because the arguments aren't available in the parent component. So, you need to accept a function as `@Input` and then execute it in the child component.

Child Component

```
@Input()
resouces$: (id: number, type: string) => Observable<DetailsResponse[]>;

// Use ngOnInit since @Input properties are populated at this time
ngOnInit() {
    // Example arguments
    this.resouces$(this.id, this.type).subscribe(results => {
        // Do whatever you need to do with the results
        console.log(results);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the typo at `service.getData()`, it is also important to know when input properties are available to be bound. Input's are not set in the constructor, they are available in the `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook every time an input changes. or in `ngOnInit` if you want to bind just the first time it is received.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `DetailsViewComponent` like the following code

```
export class DetailsViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() resouces$: (id: number, type: string) => Observable<DetailsResponse[]>;

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(data) {
    if (data.resouces$ && this.resouces$) {
      this.resouces$(this.id, this.type).subscibe(res => {});
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Arguments for `getData()` is known in the second component so it does't work

Comment: Is `id` and `type` defined when the DetailsViewComponent created?

Comment: Yes ,,,,,,,,,,,,